# How to check if a pop-up window page is already open in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am using a javascript to open a pop-up window in asp.net. What I want to do is when the pop-up window is already open, it will just set the focus on it and refresh the pop-up window rather than opening a new pop-up window. Else when it is close, that's the time that the pop-up window must open.

I tried below codes but didn't work..

```
var winPop = false; 
function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) 
 { 
   if(winPop && !winPop.closed)
   {  
     winPop.focus();  
   }  
   else
   {  
     var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
     var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
     winPop = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
     winPop.focus();     
   }  

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: var winPop = false; Should be var winPop = null;

Comment: and this variable should not in same page

Comment: @Ravindrapatankar...still didn't work sir

Comment: @J-J I don't see winPop.closed variable anywhere.Remove that check from the if statement and the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.indexOf and by using that you can check that window is opened or not from its url

and another solution as per your code is that make that variable null when your window is going to close and then check that variable is null or not when it is null open new window else set focus.

Good Luck!

-> code in Parent window
put this whole code in parent window like

var w= null;

then set variable like w= window.open();

then check that if (w!= null) then open new window else do nothing

-> Code in Popup window
and also be careful to set w= null in popup window

`$( window ).unload(function() {
          w=null;
});`

when child window is going to close.

Comment: i hope now there is no need of example isn't it?

Comment: so I will set it to null not false?

Comment: yes and this variable you should not place in this window it will not work, put it at some other place like in common.js between two pages (opener page and this window) then it will work fine

Comment: i tried changing var winPop=null but still didn't work

Comment: it didn't focus on the window pop-up page even though it's already open

Comment: where you put this variable? and initialise it with null value AND  then SET its value for window.open()

Comment: i put it outside the function

Comment: no dear if you define this variable in same page it will not work define this variable in its parent page or in another js file

Comment: still no effect..I already put the variable in the content page

Comment: i had done this kind of development and its works fine